# What is difference between CollectionUsage, PeakUsage, Usage?

Tags: java, jmx, jmx-ws

What is the difference between CollectionUsage, PeakUsage, Usage fields in any memorypool bean ?
I saw these in the path of any application in a jconsole window:
**mbeans tab > java.lang > memorypool > select any bean.** 
In the **right hand side pane** we can see these attributes.

Answer (score 5):

They're all described in the javadocs for [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)

> **Memory Usage**
>
> *The getUsage() method provides an estimate of the current usage of a
>   memory pool. For a garbage-collected
>   memory pool, the amount of used memory
>   includes the memory occupied by all
>   objects in the pool including both
>   reachable and unreachable objects.*
>
> *In general, this method is a lightweight operation for getting an
>   approximate memory usage. For some
>   memory pools, for example, when
>   objects are not packed contiguously,
>   this method may be an expensive
>   operation that requires some
>   computation to determine the current
>   memory usage. An implementation should
>   document when this is the case.*
>
> **Peak Memory Usage**
>
> *The Java virtual machine maintains the peak memory usage of a memory pool
>   since the virtual machine was started
>   or the peak was reset. The peak memory
>   usage is returned by the
>   getPeakUsage() method and reset by
>   calling the resetPeakUsage() method.*
>
> **Collection Usage Threshold**
>
> *Collection usage threshold is a manageable attribute only applicable
>   to some garbage-collected memory
>   pools. After a Java virtual machine
>   has expended effort in reclaiming
>   memory space by recycling unused
>   objects in a memory pool at garbage
>   collection time, some number of bytes
>   in the memory pools that are garbaged
>   collected will still be in use. The
>   collection usage threshold allows a
>   value to be set for this number of
>   bytes such that if the threshold is
>   exceeded, a collection usage threshold
>   exceeded notification will be emitted
>   by the MemoryMXBean. In addition, the
>   collection usage threshold count will
>   then be incremented.*
>
> *The
>   isCollectionUsageThresholdSupported()
>   method can be used to determine if
>   this functionality is supported.*
>
> *A Java virtual machine performs
>   collection usage threshold checking on
>   a memory pool basis. This checking is
>   enabled if the collection usage
>   threshold is set to a positive value.
>   If the collection usage threshold is
>   set to zero, this checking is disabled
>   on this memory pool. Default value is
>   zero. The Java virtual machine
>   performs the collection usage
>   threshold checking at garbage
>   collection time.*
>
> *Some garbage-collected memory pools
>   may choose not to support the
>   collection usage threshold. For
>   example, a memory pool is only managed
>   by a continuous concurrent garbage
>   collector. Objects can be allocated in
>   this memory pool by some thread while
>   the unused objects are reclaimed by
>   the concurrent garbage collector
>   simultaneously. Unless there is a
>   well-defined garbage collection time
>   which is the best appropriate time to
>   check the memory usage, the collection
>   usage threshold should not be
>   supported.*
>
> *The collection usage threshold is
>   designed for monitoring the memory
>   usage after the Java virtual machine
>   has expended effort in reclaiming
>   memory space. The collection usage
>   could also be monitored by the polling
>   and threshold notification mechanism
>   described above for the usage
>   threshold in a similar fashion.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It answered my question. I am now clear about it.